# Is there any way to skip the Google Captcha in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, protractor, recaptcha

I am trying to automate the Registration screen of my `Angular` app but I am not able to view the Submit button due to `Google Captcha`. Is there any method to skip the `Google Captcha` and proceed to click on the Submit button in `Protractor`? I tried using switching the frames but it didn't work out. Please help

Comment: captcha can be disabled for lower environments for sure. Look up stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*CAPTCHAs (or Completely Automated Public Turing tests to tell Computers and Humans Apart) are designed to be a gate that lets humans through and robots (programs) out.*

For reCAPTCHA v2 the story is a little different. You’re still engaging in the same 2-step process as above but you’re sending different data. In this case you need to send the reCAPTCHA sitekey which can be found on the containing , regardless of whether or not the iframe has loaded.

The response you get is a token that needs to be submitted alongside the form and needs to be entered into a hidden text field with the ID of **g-recaptcha-response**

**TL;DR**, you can't really bypass CAPTCHAs (that is basically the idea of them)